# Android library, show drawable gif in WebView

Tags: android, webview, drawable, gif

Creating an Android library and it consists of displaying a gif to the user.

From what I've read, you use a WebView to display a gif and this works to that API level 8.

So, I have it all working except showing the content, which is a drawable.

How would I get the URL for the loadUrl method to the drawable?

Normally, I'd use assets, but because this is a library, I can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Put this gif image in the assets folder.
you will be able to access the assets folder in the html webview like this

```
<img src='file:///android_asset/gif-file-name.gif\'/>
```

Comment: Being that this is a library, this doesn't work.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Library has assetts folder, I tried this and this works for me in library project.

Comment: Could you post a bit on how you got the file from an asset folder then?  I'm passing an Activity to the method, but it's for the project, not the library, and can't seem to get a resource/asset without an activity, and my library is a View, so I can't get it that way either.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: there was issue with how i provided code. I have corrected it. Since you are writing html code, you have to access this html way. I have mentioned the html code above

Comment: This references the projects (Not libraries) assets.  This is what I did initially.  Also, I actually have to do this via Java, not the html code like you said.

Comment: This should fix the issue try 
{
    // get input stream
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");
    // load image as Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    // set image to ImageView
    mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException ex) 
{
    return;
}